# how to keep BehaviorSubject data on page reload

Tags: rxjs

this is my code:

```
public storeOrchData(data: any, path: string, directRoute?: string) {
        data.forEach((item: any) => {
            this.orchDataObj[item.title] = item;
        })
        directRoute ? this.orchData.next({ parent: path, data: this.orchDataObj, directRoute: directRoute }) : this.orchData.next({ parent: path, data: this.orchDataObj })
    }
```

I would like to keep the 'orchData' values even on page refresh. Now, I have come across many similar questions and almost all of them have mentioned either local storage or session storage. I would like to know if there is any other way than local/session storage.

Comment: It would have to be something that is outside of your application. So local / session storage .. indexDB .. save on server etc.

Comment: You found it right. Local storage, session storage, index dB are the only viable options that you have if you want to preserve state over page refresh

Comment: https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra/blob/master/src/subject/PersistentSubject.ts